# I'm currently having errors when deploying my Streamlit App to Heroku

Tags: python, git, github, heroku, streamlit

I'm currently having errors when deploying my Streamlit App to Heroku.  I have done the necessary steps including the requirements.txt, setup.sh file but still having errors. What do I do?

This is the error:

```
(my_env) PS C:\Users\admin> heroku login
heroku: Press any key to open up the browser to login or q to exit:
Opening browser to https://cli-auth.heroku.com/auth/cli/browser/73a0eaad-0c35-474f-93dc-0c3cc2327186?requestor=SFMyNTY.g2gDbQAAAA4xNTIuMzIuMTA3LjIyN24GALr4ISB3AWIAAVGA.H95J-eKqdgobd7jDXEq_zqagK-kkddyNjZKvHi5K_wA
Logging in... done
Logged in as zipporah.luna@gmail.com
(my_env) PS C:\Users\admin> cd Documents\Eskwelabs\01112020\01152020                                                                                                                                                                         (my_env) PS C:\Users\admin\Documents\Eskwelabs\01112020\01152020> heroku create                                                                                                                                                              Creating app... done, ⬢ guarded-basin-48702
https://guarded-basin-48702.herokuapp.com/ | https://git.heroku.com/guarded-basin-48702.git
(my_env) PS C:\Users\admin\Documents\Eskwelabs\01112020\01152020> git add .                                                                                                                                                                  (my_env) PS C:\Users\admin\Documents\Eskwelabs\01112020\01152020> git commit -m "Enter your message here"                                                                                                                                    On branch master
nothing to commit, working tree clean
(my_env) PS C:\Users\admin\Documents\Eskwelabs\01112020\01152020> git push heroku master                                                                                                                                                     Enumerating objects: 5, done.
Counting objects: 100% (5/5), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 310 bytes | 310.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
remote: -----> Cairo app detected
remote: -----> Vendoring binaries
remote:        Fetching https://s3.amazonaws.com/mojodna-heroku/heroku-20/cairo-1.14.6-1.tar.gz
remote:
remote: gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
remote: tar: Child returned status 1
remote: tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Cairo app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote:  !
remote:  ! ## Warning - The same version of this code has already been built: 76a6a1fdca290cedbf2397e2bed1db0a1680be7e
remote:  !
remote:  ! We have detected that you have triggered a build from source code with version 76a6a1fdca290cedbf2397e2bed1db0a1680be7e
remote:  ! at least twice. One common cause of this behavior is attempting to deploy code from a different branch.
remote:  !
remote:  ! If you are developing on a branch and deploying via git you must run:
remote:  !
remote:  !     git push heroku <branchname>:main
remote:  !
remote:  ! This article goes into details on the behavior:
remote:  !   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/duplicate-build-version
remote:
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to agile-beach-04592.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/agile-beach-04592.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/agile-beach-04592.git'
(my_env) PS C:\Users\admin\Documents\Eskwelabs\01112020\01152020>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Easy Fix:

- Try to upload your code to GitHub
- Login to your Heroku Account
- Create a new app
- Connect your GitHub App
- Select the repo and the branch (assuming you don't have multiple branches it would be main)
- Choose Manual Deploy(Unless you have a CI)
- Within a couple of minutes it should be deployed

### Hosting directly by pushing from your local system

The steps are:

- heroku login
- git init
- heroku git:remote -a your-project-name-on-heroku
- git add.
- git commit -m "Anything relevant"
- git push heroku master

From your code block above I can infer that you missed out on setting the remote to your project on Heroku and committing your changes

I believe if you do these, then it should work fine.